# Will this voltage selector circuit work?

Tags: battery-charging

I recently decided to design an Arduino Uno clone with a dedicated onboard 18650 battery. As such, I began researching into voltage selectors and came up with the following schematic (PDF version [here)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HbvGtFR4h0Hfve-stwtmxUlOHxml69mG/view?usp=sharing):

[image: Schematic]

I want to achieve the following 3 things:

1. If both USB and DC barrel jack is plugged in, the voltage supply switches from USB to DC barrel jack (achieved via IC1A in "Voltage Comparators.")
2. When the DC barrel jack is plugged in, the battery charges from the regulated 5V (achieved through U$2 N-Channel MOSFET under "Battery Charging and Output Circuit.")
3. If only USB is plugged in, the voltage supply switches from battery (BATTERY_OUT) to USB (VUSB) (achieved via IC1B in "Voltage Comparators.")

Having referenced and adapted a lot of features from the [Arduino Uno Reference Design Schematic](https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/arduino-uno-schematic.pdf), I am not sure about how the voltage comparator with the Q2 and Q1 cuts off voltage from the other source since the body diode of the MOSFET would still be forward biased.

Secondly, I am unsure if achieving (2) will cause issues with the charging circuit (TP4056) as I assumed that when the N-channel MOSFET is switched off it would be akin to removing the battery which from experience with TP4056 breakout boards still produces ~5V on the output terminals.

Comment: Please use circuit diagram references rather than this P channel MOSFET or this N channel MOSFET

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.